# WebVR development on VSCode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, webvr

I'm interested in developing [WebVR](https://webvr.info/) on VSCode (Visual Studio Code).

However, I can't get IntelliSense assist from the editor.

Is there any way to enable IntelliSense from WebVR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing [@types/webvr-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/webvr-api):

```
npm install --save-dev @types/webvr-api
```

These types should augment the standard browser api typings